# Json empty array json_decode

Tags: php, arrays, json, string, decode

I have the following code that converts json into an array:

```
$str = file_get_contents('http://localhost/data.json');
$decodedstr = html_entity_decode($str);
$jarray = json_decode($decodedstr, true);


echo "<pre>";
print_r($jarray);
echo "</pre>";
```

but my `$jarray` keeps returning `null`... I dont know why this is happening.. i have already validated my json in this question:
[validated json question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43830598/json-decode-empty-array-because-of-syntaxerror) could anyone tell me what i am doing wrong? or what is happening. Thanks in advance.

when i echo my $str i get the following:[image: image of echo of $str]

Comment: Have you tried it without the `html_entity_decode` step, and just `json_decode($str, true)`?

Comment: print the `json_last_error()` after `json_decode` method

Comment: oke i tried without the html_entity_decode and it still returned null. when i print the json_last_error i get 4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing to `json_decode` a string **that is not valid JSON**, this is the reason `NULL` is returned.

As I see from comments inspecting the error code generated gives `4` that corresponds to the constant `JSON_ERROR_SYNTAX` that just means the JSON string has a **Syntax Error**.

(See http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-last-error.php)

---

You should inspect (echo) what you get from

```
$str = file_get_contents('http://localhost/data.json');
```

(You may edit your answer and post it - or a portion of it)

For sure it is not valid `JSON`; the problem lies there: in `data.json`.

Then as you fix things and get from `data.json` what is expected I would ensure you really need to use `html_entity_decode` on the fetched data.

It would be "weird" to have html encoded JSON data.

---

**UPDATE**

Looking at what you get from `data.json` it seem the JSON data contains actually HTML entities (as I see the presence of `&nbsp;`s)

This is actually weird, the right thing to do would be to fix how `data.json` is generated ensuring **non-html-encoded** JSON data is returned, charset is UTF-8 and the response content type is `Content-Type: application/json`.

We can't deepen this here as I don't know where does `data.json` come from or the code that generates it. Eventually you may post another answer.

So here is a **quick fix** provided that the right approach would be what I just suggested above.

As you decode html entities, non breaking spaces `&nbsp;` turns into 2 byte UTF-8 characters (byte values 196, 160) that are **not valid** for JSON encoded data.

The idea is to remove these characters; your code becomes:

```
$str = file_get_contents('http://localhost/data.json');
$decodedstr = html_entity_decode($str);

// the character sequence for decoded HTML &nbsp;
$nbsp = html_entity_decode( "&nbsp;" );

// remove every occurrence of the character sequence
$decodedstr = str_replace( $nbsp, "", $decodedstr );

$jarray = json_decode($decodedstr, true);
```

Comment: you are the real MVP it works thanks man! now i see what i was doing wrong thanks again :)

Answer (score 0):

from php manual

http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php

**Return**:

> ... `NULL is returned if the json cannot be decoded or if the encoded data is deeper than the recursion limit`

So, surely the JSON string passed to `json_decode()` is not valid:

maybe because of `html_entity_decode`

Comment: so if my json exceeds the recursion limit how do i fix this? the data i get is from a client. So i probably cant ask him to change the json.

Comment: @FutureCake the error is not caused by excessive recursion but by a syntax error (see my answer for details)